# How To Float Different Size DIV To Left In Perfect Grid Style?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

Here I have a problem. I have many DIVs having same width but their heights are different and are float to left but they are not appearing as I want. Its appearing as

[image]

But I want to make them like

[image]

So Tell me how can I do this using Pure HTML-CSS, No JavaScript Or JQuery etc.

Comment: here's an option for you: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: you want something called http://masonry.desandro.com/ i belive the same thing can be done with http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/

Comment: @dward I already checked it out but I want in pure CSS. :( Is there are code in CSS?

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard Its not working properly. It is breaking my DIVs and showing half in one column and other half in second column. I want to display in grid style without breaking any DIV as in [masonry.desandro.com](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: @TomChew-headMillard Here It Is. [Problem DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/UB2Lz). In addition, I want it responsive means no fixed columns count. Columns can increase as per screen size or can decrease as per screen size

Answer (score 4):

@Tom Chew-head Millard is correct; this is a purely CSS solution.  My experience = easy to use.

http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/multiple-columns/

== EDIT AFTER READING MH COMMENTS

http://jsfiddle.net/qZ3N4/1/

```
#DEMO_ID {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -moz-column-gap: 20px;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-gap: 20px;
}

#DEMO_ID div {
     column-break-before: always;   
}
```

Comment: The caveat is IE9, so a fallback could be needed.

Comment: Its not working properly. It is breaking my DIVs and showing half in one column and other half in second column. I want to display in grid style without breaking any DIV as in [masonry.desandro.com](http://masonry.desandro.com/).

Comment: Can you post your code or a URL to a site (JSFiddle)?

Comment: @UpperStage In addition, I want it responsive means no fixed columns count. Columns can increase as per screen size or can decrease as per screen size.

Comment: OK, that's cool.  You need not predetermine (fix) the number of columns.  Take the available space of the parent container (easy to determine) and divide by the width of the red divs to find the number of columns.

Yes?

Comment: @UpperStage Ok. If I keep it fix in column count but still its breaking my DIV(ul list) as you can see in [ScreenShoot](http://prntscr.com/3cvomr) and live at [Problem DEMO - 1](http://jsfiddle.net/UB2Lz/1/)

Comment: Try this: http://jsfiddle.net/qZ3N4/1/   
The trick is to use css: column-break-before: always

Comment: I just read your "must be responsive" comment.  I don't think that's practical (perhaps not possible) using only CSS.

Comment: @UpperStage Ok. No responsive but also no breaking of DIVs like in your [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/qZ3N4/1/) in this [ScreenShoot](http://prntscr.com/3cyxe9)

Comment: You might edit your question to include the "requirement" that the solution be responsive.

Comment: @UpperStage I said that now I don't want responsive. I am ok with column count but DIV should not be break as [Here](http://prntscr.com/3cyxe9)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use the `clear` property. This property states that the element that you apply it to should not touch the left or the right-hand side of the boxes that are within its containing element.

So, for example, if you have those fifteen divs inside the body, you can do something like this:

```css
div {
    float: left;
    clear: left;
}
```

This means, those fifteen boxes (that sit inside the same containing element) are allowed to touch each other on the left side.